# How to create a search spec for Query method of EAI Siebel Adapter that gets line items that has a certain child/grandchild items

Tags: xml, integration, siebel

i'm using EAI Siebel Adapter:Query

how can i put in XML:

-parent and child with special as grandchild and child respectively

-do not put parent/child/anotherparent/anotherparent2 without special

1. parent

--2. child

---3. special

--4. anotherparent

---5. child

----6. special

--7. anotherparent

8. parent
9. anotherparent2

only 1,2,3,4,5,6 should be in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Assuming special is at grandchild level and you only need child records which have at least one grandchild (special), you could try

[special.rowid] IS NOT NULL

Every special record should have a row id, and you can use this to filter records out. The rowid field should be exposed at Integration component field level too.